# Can not ping other nodes in private network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, routing

I am setting up a small cluster (four nodes running ubuntu14) and I have this configuration:

```
# Internet and lab - 192.168.10.0/24
iface eth0 inet dhcp
dns-nameservers 192.168.100.1

# privte network
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.30.20
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.30.0
```

Internet connection works fine, and I can ssh nodes in network `192.168.10.0/24`. but when I try to ping nodes in network `192.168.30.0/24` I get a `destination host unreachable` error.

I enabled ip_forwarding by editing both `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and `/etc/sysctl.conf` on all nodes, but still I can not reach nodes using the other ethernet interface.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.30.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

`ip route show` gives the following output:

```
default via 192.168.10.254 dev eth0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.60 
192.168.30.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.20
```

what can possibly be the problem? am I missing something?

Comment: Is eth1 up?  Can you see traffic on it via tcpdump?

Answer (score 4):

on each node, check:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

if it is 1, change to 0:

```
echo 0 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

Comment: it is already zero. what's its meaning?

Comment: If this was '1' then the machine does not respond to any pings. But evidently your problem is different...

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know the Unix or Unix-like O/S and version because  software and file locations can differ. If I understand the problem, you want each machine to have WAN access using `eth0` and LAN access using `eth1`.

For any Linux, make a new routing table for `eth1`, naming the network "mgmt", or whichever name you like.

```
echo '200 mgmt' >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

For a Debian-based system...

```
# /etc/network/interfaces

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
dns-nameservers 192.168.100.1

auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.30.20
netmask 255.255.255.0
post-up ip route add 192.168.30.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.30.20 table mgmt
post-up ip route add default via 192.168.30.1 dev eth1 table mgmt
post-up ip rule add from 192.168.30.20/32 table mgmt
post-up ip rule add to 192.168.30.20/32 table mgmt
```

I could post the same solution for RHEL-based system or Void-based system if you like. This works great on machines with multiple NICs.

The `dns-nameservers` line is for Network Manager, right? I do not know if manual configurations like this work with network managers.

Comment: I edited the question, adding OS and version and the output from `ip route show`. I'm sorry but I don't understand some parts of your answer (I probably lack some basic networking concepts): what's `200 mgmt` for? why adding a default route via `192.168.30.1`? and why did you write the address as `192.168.30.20/32`?

Comment: I tried adding routes as showed, still can't ping nodes in network `192.168.30.0/24`.  I even tried with `ping -I eth1 192.168.30.18`

Comment: `200 mgmt` is a named routing table. I imagined that `192.168.30.1` could be the IP address of the router for the `192.168.30.0/24` network, but use the actual IP address of the router for that network. Using `/32` is CIDR notation for a specific address. The "default route" for Internet traffic is provided by DHCP, but the "default route" for all traffic to or from the `192.168.30.0/24` network traverses over `192.168.30.20`. You might want to disable network managers and go with a manual configuration, including `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: This is a routing question. It becomes a forwarding question when, for example, a Linux host is used as a router. Or, it's not about packet forwarding, but choosing which direction the packets should go.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I'm actually using a manual configuration, and network manager is disabled. When you said it is a routing question, I went back to the routing rules, and delete the rule at line 2 (`169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000`), which was present in all machines, but I did not add it. nothing changed and I still can't ping the nodes through the second NIC